Are the drivers used by the 2080ti and A5000 different?
A friend who was using a 2080ti requested to replace it with an A5000
ubuntu 20.04 or 22.04 maybe..
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get -y install ubuntu-drivers-common
ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo apt install -y nvidia-driver-???
sudo reboot
nvidia-smi
it is good?
And he also uses cuda, should I reinstall that too? cuda, cudnn...etc
help...!!!

Accurate details help a lot. For example the Ubuntu version.  What is this nvidia-driver-???

??? is the value recommended through ubuntu-drivers devices. ex sudo apt install -y nvidia-driver-550

never use "*" in apt purge. It is not used as a wildcard by apt.

So how do I get rid of the existing drivers? * Would it be better to use tabtab key to find the exact driver name instead?

Old drivers are automatically removed/disabled when you activate a new one (only 1 driver per card is allowed to remain on a system). Only if you switch between 2 brands (amd <> nvidia <> ATI (:)) ) you should switch to the open source one prior. All newish nvidia cards are likely to work (but maybe not optimal) with any of the newish nvidia drivers.

Yes, to OP question.
